# How do I create a loop for my racing simulation properly?

Tags: python, list

I created this code to run a simulation of a race across the screen, but I am having trouble building the UI and how to continue the build. My objectives are to create the runner position starting at 0, to the position of 20. Each 0 represents an 'R' that races across the screen st random times. So each time I press the keyboard, the 0 would either turn to a 1 or stay at the zero position. I also need help to establish the UI to build the starting position of R's in a row of 4 and 19 dashes.
Here's an example of what is supposed to look like UI wise.

```
R-------------------------- 
R-------------------------- 
R--------------------------
R--------------------------
```

Here is my current code. Thank you

```
    import random


#Create a list of the runners' positions [0,0,0,0]
runnerPos = [0,0,0,0]
raceFinished = False

  
while raceFinished == False:
  #Loop through the list, 50% chance to increase the positions runnerPos[index] += 1
    for x in range(0,4):
      if random.randint(0,1) == 0:
        runnerPos[x] += 1
  
  #loop to continue the race
 
      
    
  #Test print the list
  print(runnerPos)
  input()
```

Once it reaches the 20th position I need it to end the race and state which R has won
I hope this is a good enough explanation if not here are more details below.

***This program will be a simple simulation of a 20-yard dash. The race will be advanced every time you hit the enter button and the runner will have a 50% chance of advancing forward 1 space***

***Requirements:
The race track will be represented by 20 dash characters (-) while the runner will be represented by the letter R (see below).
Every time you hit enter, the runner will have a 50% chance of moving forward.
When the runner reaches the end of the race, the winner will be declared.***

Python 3.8.2 (default, Feb 26 2020, 02:56:10)

Comment: If you need more info please tell me

Answer (score 0):

You can print the lines in the loop you already have. Use string multiplication to print the dashes.

```
import random

#Create a list of the runners' positions [0,0,0,0]
runnerPos = [0,0,0,0]
raceFinished = False
  
while raceFinished == False:
  #Loop through the list, 50% chance to increase the positions runnerPos[index] += 1
    for x in range(0,4):
      if random.randint(0,1) == 0:
         runnerPos[x] += 1
      print('-'*runnerPos[x] + 'R' + '-'*(20-runnerPos[x]))
    if max(runnerPos) > 19: break
    print()
      
#Test print the list
print(runnerPos)
input()
```

Output

```
-R-------------------
R--------------------
-R-------------------
-R-------------------

--R------------------
-R-------------------
-R-------------------
-R-------------------

--R------------------
-R-------------------
--R------------------
--R------------------

.......

-------------------R-
---------------R-----
-----------------R---
----------------R----

--------------------R
----------------R----
------------------R--
----------------R----

[20, 16, 18, 16]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use python `list` subscriptions:

```
from random import randint as rt

race = ['R--------------------------',
        'R--------------------------',
        'R--------------------------',
        'R--------------------------']

racing = True
while racing:
    print('\n'.join(race))
    input()
    for i in range(len(race)):
        if rt(0, 1):
            race[i] = '-' + race[i][:-1]
    for i, v in enumerate(race):
        if 'R' not in v:
            print(f'Racer number {i+1} won!')
            racing = False
```

Test run!

```
R--------------------------
R--------------------------
R--------------------------
R--------------------------

R--------------------------
R--------------------------
-R-------------------------
-R-------------------------

R--------------------------
-R-------------------------
--R------------------------
-R-------------------------

R--------------------------
--R------------------------
--R------------------------
--R------------------------

R--------------------------
---R-----------------------
--R------------------------
--R------------------------

-R-------------------------
---R-----------------------
---R-----------------------
--R------------------------

--R------------------------
----R----------------------
----R----------------------
--R------------------------

--R------------------------
-----R---------------------
----R----------------------
---R-----------------------

---R-----------------------
------R--------------------
-----R---------------------
---R-----------------------

----R----------------------
------R--------------------
-----R---------------------
----R----------------------

----R----------------------
-------R-------------------
-----R---------------------
----R----------------------

----R----------------------
--------R------------------
------R--------------------
----R----------------------

----R----------------------
---------R-----------------
-------R-------------------
----R----------------------

----R----------------------
----------R----------------
-------R-------------------
----R----------------------

-----R---------------------
-----------R---------------
--------R------------------
-----R---------------------

------R--------------------
------------R--------------
--------R------------------
-----R---------------------

------R--------------------
------------R--------------
--------R------------------
-----R---------------------

-------R-------------------
-------------R-------------
---------R-----------------
-----R---------------------

--------R------------------
--------------R------------
----------R----------------
-----R---------------------

---------R-----------------
---------------R-----------
-----------R---------------
------R--------------------

---------R-----------------
----------------R----------
------------R--------------
-------R-------------------

---------R-----------------
----------------R----------
-------------R-------------
--------R------------------

----------R----------------
----------------R----------
-------------R-------------
--------R------------------

-----------R---------------
----------------R----------
--------------R------------
---------R-----------------

-----------R---------------
-----------------R---------
--------------R------------
----------R----------------

------------R--------------
------------------R--------
---------------R-----------
-----------R---------------

------------R--------------
-------------------R-------
----------------R----------
------------R--------------

------------R--------------
-------------------R-------
-----------------R---------
-------------R-------------

-------------R-------------
-------------------R-------
------------------R--------
-------------R-------------

--------------R------------
-------------------R-------
------------------R--------
--------------R------------

--------------R------------
-------------------R-------
------------------R--------
--------------R------------

---------------R-----------
--------------------R------
-------------------R-------
--------------R------------

----------------R----------
---------------------R-----
-------------------R-------
---------------R-----------

-----------------R---------
----------------------R----
-------------------R-------
----------------R----------

-----------------R---------
-----------------------R---
--------------------R------
-----------------R---------

-----------------R---------
-----------------------R---
---------------------R-----
------------------R--------

-----------------R---------
------------------------R--
----------------------R----
-------------------R-------

-----------------R---------
------------------------R--
----------------------R----
-------------------R-------

------------------R--------
------------------------R--
----------------------R----
-------------------R-------

------------------R--------
------------------------R--
-----------------------R---
--------------------R------

-------------------R-------
------------------------R--
-----------------------R---
---------------------R-----

-------------------R-------
------------------------R--
-----------------------R---
---------------------R-----

--------------------R------
-------------------------R-
-----------------------R---
---------------------R-----

---------------------R-----
--------------------------R
------------------------R--
----------------------R----

Racer number 2 won!
```